# Liferay 6.2 - Duplicate web pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

noob question. My site looks like this:

```
- Public pages
   - Home
      - My site
           - A
              - A 1
                   - A 1.1
                   - A 1.2
              - A 2
           - B
              - B 1
                   - B 1.1
                   - B 1.2
              - B 2
```

And now I have to create C, D, E, etc. web page trees. So, how can I do it without doing it manually? I've tried to export the "A" tree and import again but it doesn't work because it is imported to the same place "A" tree was. Is there any way to import as a copy or something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest close match I can find is:-

[image: copy a page]

You have an option to copy a page while you create the page.
The proper way is to create a resource importer in a theme and initialize the whole site. Like it is already done by Liferay for their default site and theme.

Comment: But this copies pages one by one. I need something to copy several pages at a time